# How to clear a Text Input in power automate desktop

Tags: power-automate

How to clear a Textbox  in power automate desktop flow ?
My flow can key a 'hello' string in a windows textbox.
Every thing seems perfect, but run the flow second time the textbox content become to 'hellohello'.
So  I need  clear the textbox first before key in 'hello'.   How to do it?

Comment: You can  answer me .  I will chose you the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send keys by using {Control}({A}) {Delete}

Comment: {Control}({A}) {Delete}